# Custom compare function for std::multimap when keys are equal

Tags: c++, c++11, multimap, custom-compare

I would like to code a custom comparator for a `std::multimap`. What I would like to do is to compare the *keys*, in case they are equal, then compare the *values*. I'm trying to do it by overloading the `operator()` in a struct and passing the function object as a third parameter in the `std::multimap` constructor.

```
struct CustomComp {
    bool operator()(int key_lhs, int key_rhs){
        if (key_lhs < key_rhs) return true;
        if (key_lhs == key_rhs) //Check values;
        else return false;
    }
};

multimap<int, int, CustomComp> myMap;
```

How can I access the values, not only the keys, if both are int?

Comment: This is not how hashmaps works. You only hash the key, not the value. There is no way to access the value, unless you put the value inside of the key-struct (which would be an overkill and waste memory)

Comment: why would you want to do that? Smells like a [xy problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). What would be the use case? what do you actually want to achieve?

Comment: well ok, the "what do you want to do?" is more or less clear, but why does it have to be a `multimap` ? You could use a `std::map<key, some_sorted_container<value> >` instead, would that be fine?

Comment: Anything being key compared needs to be part of the key. Period. (its a world gone mad, I know).

Comment: What you want to do is not possible. You should tell us why you need such a structure: What do you want to with it? How do you want to access elements? Insert elements? etc. If you can give us the requirements on the structure, we can start giving you advice on which structure is the best for you.

Comment: The answer below looks interesting. What I want to do is exactly what I explained before. I have a group of pair of int, i.e: (2,3), (2,4), (4,4) (4,5) and I want to sort them not only taking into account the first value, also the second one. In case I have (2,4) and (2,3), I want (2, 3) first no matter if it arrives later to the container.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> What I would like to do is to compare the keys, in case they are
>   equal, **then compare the values**.

No, you can not make a comparison for `std::multimap` according to the **values**.

I would suggest using `std::vector< std::pair<int, int> >` instead and simply sort. The [operator<](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/pair/operator_cmp) of `std::pair`  will take care of what you want.

<kbd>**[See output here](https://wandbox.org/permlink/cS4RUbixn9KuoLve)**</kbd>

```
std::vector< std::pair<int, int> > vec{ {1,2}, {1,-1},{ 2,2 } ,{ -1,1 } };
std::sort(std::begin(vec), std::end(vec));
```

---

**Update**: After reading the other answer(i.e, `std::multiset<std::tuple<int, int>>`), I was thinking about, how bad is the `std::multiset::insert`.

Then I came up with the following benchmark, which shows, why should be `std::vector` at first place in the above problem.

See <kbd>**[Quick benchmark online here](http://quick-bench.com/qDbWkgJ6cxL05LteYdWdaCMNMDo)**</kbd>

[image: Vector-Sort Vs Multimap-Insertion]

Comment: That is exactly what I was looking for. Thank you.

Comment: Owesome!, I am interested in high-perfomance as well. Thanks again. I see results scale the same when compiler optimizations are out, pure algorithm performance due to pick the right data structure.

Answer (score 2):

You can achieve the desired effect with `std::multiset<std::tuple<int, int>>`. No custom comparator is necessary because `std::tuple` uses lexicographical comparison (the one you are trying to implement).

Comment: That's look interesting. Citing: "In a multiset, the value of an element also identifies it". http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/set/multiset/